# aspnet_regiis -pe cannot find my configuration section in .net v4.0.30319

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encryption, configuration-files, configurationsection, aspnet-regiis.exe

I've added a new **Settings.settings** file to my ASP.NET Webclient project; I am having a problem encrypting the section. In the cmd window positioned to this directory:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>
```

Here is my syntax:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "Webclient.Properties.Settings" -app "/sdkTrimFileServiceASMXclient"
```

Output:

```
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'Webclient.Properties.Settings' was not found.
Failed!
```

My project is called **Webclient**; I clicked on the *Settings* tab and added 2 elements. Visual Studio 2010 added the Settings.settings file and updated my web.config as follows:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" 
            type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">

        <section name="WebClient.Properties.Settings" 
            type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
            requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="FileServiceProxy.Properties.Settings" 
            type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
            requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings>
      <WebClient.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="GROUPERpassword" serializeAs="String">
              <value>12345abcde</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="MARLINpassword" serializeAs="String">
              <value>abcdef12345</value>
          </setting>
      </WebClient.Properties.Settings>

      <FileServiceProxy.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="FileServiceProxy_ASMXproxy_FileService" serializeAs="String">
              <value>http://MDWDATA/sdkTrimFileServiceASMX/FileService.asmx</value>
          </setting>
      </FileServiceProxy.Properties.Settings>

  </applicationSettings>
```

I have also tried this syntax (i.e. just **"Webclient"** rather than **"Webclient.Properties.Settings"**) and I get the same failure as above.

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "Webclient" -app "/sdkTrimFileServiceASMXclient"
```

In the Default Web Site on my **IIS 6.0 Windows 2003 Server** machine, I have a virtual directory called: **sdkTrimFileServiceASMXclient**

The local path to the physical directory: **C:\ProjectsVS2010\sdkTrimFileServiceASMX\WebClient**

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

------------------------------ EDIT UPDATE --------------------------- 13 Dec 2011
A suggestion was made to try this syntax (but I got the same error):

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pe "applicationSettings/Webclient" -app "/sdkTrimFileServiceASMXclient"

Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'applicationSettings/Webclient' was not found.
Failed!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"applicationSettings/WebClient"` instead of just `"WebClient"` in your script.

This command is case sensitive, as @John Adams said in his comment below.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it as shown in the EDIT UPDATE to original post. Got the same result.

Comment: Hopefully, you saw my comment "the change did NOT work". I get the same "....not found.." error.

Comment: On a different forum, someone pointed out that the real problem was the fact that the XML is case-sensitive and that in the command, I needed to specify 'applicationSettings/WebClient' instead of 'applicationSettings/Webclient'. The latter was, of course, not found in the web.config with that spelling. Finally, case closed. NOTE to someone who can EDIT the answer: improve the answer to reflect this comment added by me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By @John Adams

"On a different forum, someone pointed out that the real problem was the fact that the XML is case-sensitive and that in the command, I needed to specify 'applicationSettings/WebClient' instead of 'applicationSettings/Webclient'. The latter was, of course, not found in the web.config with that spelling. Finally, case closed. NOTE to someone who can EDIT the answer: improve the answer to reflect this comment added by me. Thanks"

Answer (score 0):

It is not an optimal solution, but changing the name of a file to `web.config` should do the job.